# malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fd4f4c8bbd0: probably modified after being freed

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

I'm trying to write a parser to import OBJ files, but even at this early stage I am experiencing the following error on execution:

```
malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fd4f4c8bbd0: probably modified after being freed.
```

It manages to print the buffer size each line, so I'm wondering if the issue is connected to closing the file after the operation.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm running on macOS.

```
int Utilities_Import_OBJ(const char *filename) {
    // input checking
    if (filename == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to parse file, filename was NULL.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char *path = strcat(_resource_path, filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    // create a line buffer
    const int length = 1024;
    char buffer[length];

    int index = 0;

    // fgets stops reading at a \n and appends \0   
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) {
        printf("Buffer size at line %d : %d\n", index, sizeof(buffer));
        index++;
    }

    // done with file, so close it
    if (fclose(file) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to close file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `malloc` in this code. Please post [mcve].

Comment: Aside: I would not `strcat(_resource_path, filename);` it looks dangerous, but create the file path in `buffer` with `strcpy` and `strcat` (or `snprintf`).

Comment: Can you post code that can compile/run/debug?   Alternatively, you can debug it by following this [instruction](https://www.cee.studio/segfault.html)

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, I re-read the documentation for strcat, and appending the extension to the destination string was not what I wanted at all! I'm working with a local copy in buffer now. Thanks for your help, and every one else who reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 surprising lines in your code:

- `char *path = strcat(_resource_path, filename);`

  `strcat` does not concatenate 2 strings into a third allocated one. It copies the second string at the end of the first. Depending on how `_resource_path` is allocated, it is quite possible that this very line corrupt the `malloc()` internal data and ultimately produces the problem. You should write a specific function like this:

  ```
  char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
      size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
      size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
      char *p = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
      if (p) {
          memcpy(p, s1, len1);
          memcpy(p + len1, s2, len2 + 1);
      }
      return p;
  }
  ```

  And you would `free` the string returned by `char *path = concat(_resource_path, filename);` after use.
- `printf("Buffer size at line %d : %d\n", index, sizeof(buffer));`

  The buffer size is constant, `sizeof(buffer)` always evaluates to the value `length` had at the point `buffer` was defined (1024). Furthermore, you should use `%zu` for a `size_t` argument, not `%d`, which expects an `int`, that may have a different size. You might want to write this instead:

  ```
  printf("Buffer length at line %d: %zu\n", index, strlen(buffer));
  ```